# libmysqlclient race condition

Tags: c++, mysql, multithreading

I have multiple threads that need to connect to a single instance of MySQL server.
If every thread creates and handles its own connection everything works out as expected.
I wanted to implement a simple connection pool as this :

```
void query_user(MYSQL* conn) 
{
  mysql_thread_init();

  std::ostringstream query;
  query << "select * from user u where u.username = '" << "stack" << "'";

  if (mysql_query(conn, query.str().c_str())) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
    exit(-1);
  }

  MYSQL_RES* res = mysql_use_result(conn);

  MYSQL_ROW row;
  while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) != NULL) {
    printf("%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s\n", 
       row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8]);
  }

  mysql_free_result(res);

  mysql_thread_end();
 }

#define POOL_SIZE 2

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
  mysql_library_init(argc, argv, NULL); 

  // Create Connection pool

  MYSQL* connection_pool[POOL_SIZE];

  for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(connection_pool)/sizeof(MYSQL*); ++i) {
    connection_pool[i] = mysql_init(NULL);

    if (!mysql_real_connect(connection_pool[i], server,
                user, password, database, 0, NULL, 0)) {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(connection_pool[i]));
      exit(-1);
    }
  }

  // Thread Pool
  pthread_t thread_pool[POOL_SIZE];

  for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(thread_pool)/sizeof(pthread_t); ++i) {
    pthread_create(&thread_pool[i], NULL, 
               reinterpret_cast<void* (*)(void*)>(query_user), 
           (void*)&connection_pool[i]);
  }

  // join threads
  for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(thread_pool)/sizeof(pthread_t); ++i) {
        pthread_join(thread_pool[i], NULL);
    mysql_close(connection_pool[i]);
  }

  mysql_library_end();

  return 0;
}
```

I have a bus error in mysql_real_query

Could you please point out what's wrong with it ?
Are there still some benefits from connection pooling ?

I'm linking against libmysqlclient_r which is supposed to be thread safe

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is something wrong with:

```
(void*)&connection_pool[i]
```

IMHO should be:

```
(void*)connection_pool[i]
```

Comment: Thank you very much that was the messy part! have a good day :)